# AgGrid crashes on re-render in React application

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ag-grid

I have a React + Typescript application that displays data using AgGrid. The data is fetched from a server and then fed to AgGrid, and we have multiple options that the user can interact with that could potentially change the data displayed, such as Filters, paging, and some other custom stuff.

The data that is displayed is first fetched and then displayed in full. For example, we fetch 25 rows and display all of them, we are not using any of AgGrid's paging features.

If a user makes a change to one of the parameters and the data *doesn't* change (for example, adding a filter which captures every single item already displayed), the data will be re-fetched, and then fed to AgGrid again, however this will cause AgGrid to crash.

This only happens when the data doesn't change.

The error that is occuring is the following:

```
The above error occurred in the <AgGridReact> component:
    in AgGridReact (at ag-collections/index.tsx:250)
    in div (at ag-collections/index.tsx:240)
    in div (created by ForwardRef(Paper))
    in ForwardRef(Paper) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(Paper)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Paper)) (at ag-collections/index.tsx:225)
    in main (at main/index.tsx:59)
    in div (at main/index.tsx:36)
    in Component (created by WithStyles(Component))
    in WithStyles(Component) (at ag-collections/index.tsx:218)
    in TableAg (created by Context.Consumer)
    in Connect(TableAg) (created by Connect(TableAg))
    in Connect(TableAg) (created by Context.Consumer)
    in withRouter(Connect(TableAg)) (created by WithStyles(withRouter(Connect(TableAg))))
    in WithStyles(withRouter(Connect(TableAg))) (created by Context.Consumer)
    in Route (at routes.tsx:20)
    in Switch (at routes.tsx:16)
    in Routes (at app.tsx:50)
    in ThemeProvider (at app.tsx:48)
    in Route (created by QueryParamProvider)
    in QueryParamProvider (at app.tsx:47)
    in Provider (at app.tsx:46)
    in App (at src/index.tsx:8)
    in Router (created by HashRouter)
    in HashRouter (at src/index.tsx:7)

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit <link removed> to learn more about error boundaries. index.js:1437
TypeError: can't define property "areEquivPropertyTracking": Array is not extensible
changeDetectionService.js:147
TypeError: can't define property "areEquivPropertyTracking": Array is not extensible
```

The line in question in `changeDetectionService.js` is:

```js
      if (newA) {
        a.areEquivPropertyTracking = []; // LINE 147
      } else if (a.areEquivPropertyTracking.some(function (other) {
        return other === b;
      })) return true;

      if (newB) {
        b.areEquivPropertyTracking = [];
      } else if (b.areEquivPropertyTracking.some(function (other) {
        return other === a;
      })) {
        return true;
      }
```

As far as I can tell, they are trying to create a new item on the object a, but this is being forbidden.

If I need to provide anything else I can try to do so. How can I go about fixing this?

Comment: you need to provide a reproducible example, e.g. a StackBlitz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the data that is being provided is immutable, then you won't be able to perform a deep check as this attempts to extend the objects provided.

There are, however, multiple data change detection strategies that can be used.

I solved this issue by adding the following to the AgGridReact component:

```js
import { ChangeDetectionStrategyType } from 'ag-grid-react/lib/changeDetectionService'
...
<AgGridReact
rowDataChangeDetectionStrategy={ChangeDetectionStrategyType.IdentityCheck}
...
/>
```

which will be sufficient.

I was lead to this by [this](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues/3590) github answer by @benhodeda, which says:

> hi :)
>   I had a similar problem when I've migrated our state object to use immer instead of immutableJS .
>   We bind the state to AgGridReact's rowData prop, and when we filter the data (server-side filtering) the app was crash while doing change detection. I added deltaRowDataMode prop alongside with getRowNodeId={row => row.id} on AgGridReact component.
>
> you can read more here: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-data-update/

Answer (score 0):

This can also be handled by using the `immutableData` prop set to `true` -  the grid will then use the `ChangeDetectionStrategyType.IdentityCheck` as the `rowDataChangeDetectionStrategy` by default

See the AG Grid docs for more:
https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/fine-tuning/#row-data-control
https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/immutable-data/